# How do I make a variable go from True to False before everything else?

Tags: java

I have a project where I need to

1. Create a sticker.
2. Have the sticker play a sound upon clicking on it.
3. Have the next click replicate and place the sticker. (has to be able to be placed as many times as I want without going back and clicking the original sticker again.)
4. Be able to click on another sticker and choose that one to place.

In my code, I have all my sticker variables start off as false. Once the right conditions are met, 1 sticker variable will be true and I will be able to place the sticker. But when I click on the second sticker, the first sticker is still true and will place a sticker on the second sticker. I don't want that. How do I  change the sticker variable to false when I release the left mouse on the second sticker. My code makes it change it to false after. I want before. Please help. Thank you.

```
boolean hatSoundPlay = false;
boolean bluntSoundPlay = false;
boolean dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
boolean weedSoundPlay = false;
while(true) { 
    int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse(); 
    int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse();  

    if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){ 

        if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
            bluntSoundPlay = false;
            weedSoundPlay = false;
            dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
            if (!hatSoundPlay) {
                hatsound.play(); 
                hatSoundPlay = true; 
            }
        }
        else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && hatSoundPlay == true && EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){ 
            EZ.addImage("hat.png", clickX, clickY);
                        hatsound.play();        
        }

        if (bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
            hatSoundPlay = false;
            weedSoundPlay = false;
            dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
            if (!bluntSoundPlay) {
                    bluntsound.play(); 
                    bluntSoundPlay = true;
            } 
        }
        else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && bluntSoundPlay == true && EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){
            EZ.addImage("blunt.png", clickX, clickY);
                bluntsound.play();
        }

        if (dealwithitPicture.isPointInElement(clickX,  clickY)){                       hatSoundPlay = false;
             bluntSoundPlay = false;
             weedSoundPlay = false;
             if (!dealwithitSoundPlay) {
                dealwithitsound.play(); 
                dealwithitSoundPlay = true;
              } 
        }
        else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && dealwithitSoundPlay == true && EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){
             EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png", clickX, clickY);
                dealwithitsound.play();             
        }

        if (weedPicture.isPointInElement(clickX,  clickY)){ 
            dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
            hatSoundPlay = false;
            bluntSoundPlay = false;
            if (!weedSoundPlay) {
                weedsound.play(); //then weedsound will play
                weedSoundPlay = true;
            } 
        }   
        else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && weedSoundPlay == true && EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){
            EZ.addImage("weed.png", clickX, clickY);
                weedsound.play();
        }
    }

    EZ.refreshScreen();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check if the point is in the area of one sticker. If not, check another sticker and so on. Only after checking all the stickers and setting the appropriate booleans should you deal with placing the stickers.

Also instead of 4 booleans it would probably be better to have one variable representing the currently active sticker.

In pseudocode, something like

```
if (point in hat) {
    set hat
} else if (point in blunt) {
    set blunt
} else if ...
  ...
} else {
    place the active sticker
}
```

So your code would look like this:

```
    if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
        bluntSoundPlay = false;
        weedSoundPlay = false;
        dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
        if (!hatSoundPlay) {
            hatsound.play(); 
            hatSoundPlay = true; 
        }
    } else if (bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
        hatSoundPlay = false;
        weedSoundPlay = false;
        dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
        if (!bluntSoundPlay) {
            bluntsound.play(); 
            bluntSoundPlay = true;
        } 
    } else if (dealwithitPicture.isPointInElement(clickX,  clickY)){
         hatSoundPlay = false;
         bluntSoundPlay = false;
         weedSoundPlay = false;
         if (!dealwithitSoundPlay) {
             dealwithitsound.play(); 
             dealwithitSoundPlay = true;
         } 
    } else if (weedPicture.isPointInElement(clickX,  clickY)){ 
         dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
         hatSoundPlay = false;
         bluntSoundPlay = false;
         if (!weedSoundPlay) {
             weedsound.play(); //then weedsound will play
             weedSoundPlay = true;
         } 
    } else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) { 
        if (hatSoundPlay){ 
            EZ.addImage("hat.png", clickX, clickY);
            hatsound.play();        
        } else if (bluntSoundPlay){
            EZ.addImage("blunt.png", clickX, clickY);
            bluntsound.play();
        } else if (dealwithitSoundPlay){
            EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png", clickX, clickY);
            dealwithitsound.play();
        } else if (weedSoundPlay){
            EZ.addImage("weed.png", clickX, clickY);
            weedsound.play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would I check if that area has a sticker or not?

Comment: @user5329697 you are already doing that - `hatPicture.isPointInElement(...)`. You just need to check all the non-background pictures first, before you place a new sticker.

Comment: Does this not work? `if (bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
            hatSoundPlay = false;
            weedSoundPlay = false;
            dealwithitSoundPlay = false;` It turns everything false after it checks. I'm sorry, I don't really understand how to check all non-background pictures first.

Comment: If `hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)` is false, then the `else` part get executed and you place a sticker, even when you shouldn't (e.g. when `bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)` is true).